# MySQL unexpected result

Tags: mysql

I have this data:

```
id  message_id  recipient   user_id area    name
1   1754        0           95      1       Ruecker
2   1754        1           1       4       Heller
3   1754        2           2       1       Kuhn
4   1754        2           3       4       Schuster
```

**I would like to get results where user_id!=1 and area!=4 (excluding Heller). So I want to get rows with ids: 1,3,4.**

I tried this code:

```
select * from `message_participants` 
where `message_id` = 1754 and (`user_id` != 1 and `area` != 4)
```

I am getting only Ruecker and Kuhn. 
Schuster is also being excluded.

**Can someone please explain why?**

I have settled for this query (for now) - but it seems like an overkill:

```
select * from `message_participants` 
where `message_id` = 1754 and 
`id` NOT IN (select id from `message_participants` 
             where `message_id` = 1754 and `user_id` = 1 and `area` = 4)
```

Comment: can you please share your expected output

Comment: what you get as result is correct, by specifying `and 'area' != 4` you remove Schuster from the possible results. Maybe you need an OR?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I updated question

Comment: @Signo That is interesting - it seems to work with OR. When I changed Kuhn user_id to 1, it still worked with OR.  Interesting. It goes against logic. It seems to check first condition (user_id) and then check another. So, what MySQL seems to do, is to check one AND the other condition, but it needs OR to do that. Very interesting. And VERY counter intuitive. Thanks for pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `not in()` as

```
select * from 
`message_participants` 
where `message_id` = 1754 
and (`user_id` ,`area`) not in((1,4));
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cbee6/3)

Or could use case expression

```
select * from 
`message_participants` 
where `message_id` = 1754 
and case when user_id = 1 then area <> 4 else 1 end;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cbee6/4)

Answer (score 1):

The reason Schuster is also being excluded because it has area = 4 which you are excluding by the line that states `area != 4`.

The `( )` isnt going to make the query sort by userid 1 and area 4 together, it will do that for all of the results. Which in turn sorts out Schuster because of the area value.

this is a possible solution for you by using `or`:

```
select * from `message_participants` 
where `message_id` = 1754 and `user_id` != 1 or `area` != 4
```

Comment: It does work, problem is why? It is totally counter intuitive.

Comment: I see what you mean that it sounds counter intuitive. This works because the `or`  is checking if userid isn't 1 or area isn't 4 which is more like what you want by both being that value.  With `and` it is just going to see if any of those != to the values you want @Jeffz

Comment: Yes, but this only work with parentheses: select * from `message_participants` where `message_id` = 1754 and (`user_id` != 1 or `area` != 4). Weird ... logic wise.